# Unwrap value from IO

Tags: haskell

I have got a constant `l` in `ghci`. And when I put:
`:t l` I got `IO ((), Stack EnvEval)`
Now, I would like to get `Stack EnvEval` in another constant- something like:
`let second = giveMeSecond l`. How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ghci executes within `IO` so you can bind it with `<-`:

```
(_, second) <- l
```